# c++ most efficient way to send n chars from ifstream to cout

Tags: c++

I have an ifstream (a binary file on my disk) that I have read up to some point.
Next I need to send some pre-determined amount of data from this point of the ifstream directly to cout (I know in advance that they will be ascii chars).
What is an(/the most) efficient way (in terms of execution time)?

I have a preference for a solution that works in C++11 or before.

Comment: Try `std::copy`.

Comment: Just reference the same `rdbuf()` buffer?